# Recreating IndexedDB database from zero when HTML changes

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am not very proficient on frontend topics and I am trying to find a way to reset indexeddb database completely on onupgradeneeded, which should be triggered every time the html changes.
Ho can I accomplish that?

So far I rely on clearing everything before reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating the HTML with a tag

```
<meta name="timestamp" content="1614722463">
```

and opening the db like:

```
window.indexedDB.open("MyDB", parseInt(document.head.getElementsByTagName('meta').namedItem('timestamp').getAttribute('content')));
```

which is almost like versioning the script so it uses a different version value each time (if anyone shows a better way to do the same without having to rely on generated meta tag I would change the selected answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```js
function onHTMLChanged() {
  var request = indexedDb.open(...);
  request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
    var db = request.result;
    for (var i = 0; i < db.objectStoreNames.length; i++) {
      db.deleteObjectStore(db.objectStoreNames[i]);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh! but will this keep the cached database in case the HTML is not changed?

Comment: I would like to code somehting like if(html.hash != indexeddb.htmlobjectstore.hash) trigger onupgradeneeded

Comment: The purpose is avoiding to increment in a harcoded way the indexeddb version var  on open() in the html on every development (html) change